# Make a list with every entry from a data-frame in rstudio

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I have a data-frame in rstudio as such:

| Animal | Color | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deer | Brown | Less than 3 |
| Pig | Green | More than 3 |

I want a list as such:

- Deer-Color: Brown
- Deer-Weight: Less than 3
- Pig-Color: Green
- Pig-Weight: Less than 3

How can I make that happen? There's way more entries and also more characteristics in the real-life application, and thus I would love an automated way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R using `apply` :

```
cols <- names(df)[-1]
apply(df, 1, function(x) sprintf('%s-%s', x[1], paste(cols, x[-1], sep = ':')))

#     [,1]                      [,2]                    
#[1,] "Deer-Color:Brown"        "Pig-Color:Green"       
#[2,] "Deer-Weight:Less than 3" "Pig-Weight:More than 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

If we have more columns, then an option is to use `across` to loop over the columns of interest, then with `glue` interpolate the column 'Animal' with the values of the current column along with column name of that column (`cur_column()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-Animal, ~ glue::glue("{Animal}-{cur_column()}: {.}"),
        .names = "{.col}_attributes"))
#  Animal Color      Weight  Color_attributes        Weight_attributes
#1   Deer Brown Less than 3 Deer-Color: Brown Deer-Weight: Less than 3
#2    Pig Green More than 3  Pig-Color: Green  Pig-Weight: More than 3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Animal = c("Deer", "Pig"), Color = c("Brown", 
"Green"), Weight = c("Less than 3", "More than 3")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the OP expects the output to be *reshaped in long format* (call it "list" or "vector").

Here is one possible approach which uses `melt()` and `glue_data()`. It will work with an arbitrary number of attribute columns.

```
glue::glue_data(
  data.table::melt(ds, id.var = "Animal"),
  "{Animal}-{variable}: {value}")
```

> ```
> Deer-Color: Brown
> Pig-Color: Green
> Deer-Weight: Less than 3
> Pig-Weight: More than 3
> ```

Alternatively, you may use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` for reshaping.

#### Data

```
ds <- data.table::fread(
"Animal,Color,   Weight
Deer,    Brown,   Less than 3
Pig, Green,   More than 3")
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a list like below?

```
> Map(as.list,split(df[-1],df[1]))
$Deer
$Deer$Color
[1] "Brown"

$Deer$Weight
[1] "Less than 3"


$Pig
$Pig$Color
[1] "Green"

$Pig$Weight
[1] "More than 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd break this down into smaller problems.

1. Create the Animal-attribute pairs
2. Create the "list". I'm assuming you mean vector.

```
Animal <- c("Deer", "Pig")
Color <- c("Brown", "Green")
Weight<-c("Less than 3","More than 3")

df <- data.frame(Animal, Color, Weight)

df_new<-df %>%
  mutate(Animal_attribute1=paste0(Animal,"-Color: ",Color)) %>%
  mutate(Animal_attribute2=paste0(Animal,"-Weight: ",Weight))

my_list<-c(df_new$Animal_attribute1,df_new$Animal_attribute2)
```